# Ensure data preprocessing steps are saved as part of model graph

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I’m learning Tenflow 2.0 by following these two simple tutorials:

- [TensorFlow 2 quickstart for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)
- Keras Guide:- [The Sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/)
  (Mainly to deal with structured data in BigQuery tables - no image, videos, text)

I’m looking someone to guide me as to what are best practices to ensure data preprocessing steps are saved as part of model graph when I call model.save()

As I understand in real life you always have to pre-process the raw data (normalization, binning, remove or fill NULL / missing fields, one-hot encoding categorical features, feature cross etc.). Ideally such preprocessing steps / sequence during inference should be identically same as those during training (evaluation / valuation) and making such steps as part of model graph is best way to ensure consistency between inference time and training time.

Based on my research, I came across few links that point to:

- `tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing` —> this seems only providing normalization, binning steps and misses certain other steps:- mainly remove or fill NULL / missing fields, one-hot encoding categorical features, feature cross
- Keras API provides `to_categorical()` but it doe snot look it can be exported a part of model graph
- `tf.Transform` Package:- this looks bit advanced topic to me at the moment (more low level API). I prefer to stick to high level APIs (Keras Sequential) as much a possible for time being.

Please advice if something I’m missing, or I really get to more low level APIs to be able to achieve above goals?

Comment: You could create custom layers or Lambda layers containing the preprocessing functions. If you do not want to train you model with these layers, then you can also add them later and create a new model, where first few layers are the preprocessing layers and the last "layer" is the trained model (Functional API).

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It dint come to me before.

Comment: I’m also looking forward to hear from other practitioners (what others do or is there any standard approach?)